# How to add a new node to a mongodb replica set in docker swarm (docker compose 3.4)

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, ansible, replicaset, swarm

I'm trying to intialize a mongo replica set mode and add two nodes(swarm services) to it, I'm using docker-compose 3.4
I'm using a script shell that I execute on an ansible playbook (version 2.7.10)

The following pieces of code are respectively the docker-compose, the ansible playbook and the shell script:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongodb:4.0.9-debian8-1
    command: mongod --smallfiles --replSet rs_mongo --port 27017
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - /opt/application/fwcwas/mongo/:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.mongo == true
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
      MONGO_REPLICATION_MODE: RS
      MONGO_REPLICATION_REPLSETNAME: rs_mongo
    networks:
        - web
  mongo02:
    image: mongodb:4.0.9-debian8-1
    command: mongod --smallfiles --replSet rs_mongo --port 27018
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    volumes:
      - /opt/application/fwcwas/mongo02/:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.mongo == true
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
      MONGO_REPLICATION_MODE: RS
      MONGO_REPLICATION_REPLSETNAME: rs_mongo
    networks:
        - web
  mongo03:
    image: mongodb:4.0.9-debian8-1
    command: mongod --smallfiles --replSet rs_mongo --port 27019
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
    volumes:
      - /opt/application/fwcwas/mongo03/:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.mongo == true
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
      MONGO_REPLICATION_MODE: RS
      MONGO_REPLICATION_REPLSETNAME: rs_mongo
    networks:
        - web
networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: mongo_network
```

Ansible playbook:

```
##########################################################
# Create a mongo replicaset using a script shell
##########################################################
    - name: Ensure replicaset rs_mongo exist
      shell: chmod +x init_replica_set.sh
      args:
        chdir: /home/docker/mongo/
      when:
        - ansible_host in groups['manager_launcher']
```

Script shell that initialize the replica set mode and add the mongo replicas(init_replica_set.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Intializing replica set on master"
replicate='rs.initiate();sleep(1000);cfg=rs.conf();cfg.members[0].host="mongo:27017";rs.reconfig(cfg);rs.add({host:"mongo02:27018",priority:0.5});rs.add({host:"mongo03:27019",priority:0.5});rs.status();'
docker exec -it $(docker ps -qf "name = mongo_mongo.1") bash -c "echo '$replicate' | mongo --port 27017 -u username -p pwd"
```

The script supposed to intialize the replica set mode of mongodb with the swarm service mongo:27017 which is the primary replica and add to it the services mongo02:27018 and mongo03:27019 but it only did the initialization with the first service mongo:27017 and when I tried  to add the nodes manually:

```
rs.add({host:"mongo02:27018",priority:0.5});
```

I got this error

```
{
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1571407148, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: mongo:27017; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: mongo02:27018 failed with Error connecting to mongo02:27018 (10.0.2.24:27018) :: caused by :: Connection refused",
        "code" : 74,
        "codeName" : "NodeNotFound",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1571407148, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"IAMJw09rJWNAcRle0WWba1eE8os="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6749137026550857730")
                }
        }
}
```

any advice please

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to initialize a replica set by defining all the parameters for the replica set at the same time.  i.e., call init and add together...

Also, make sure each node can reach the others by hostname.

**Example:**

```
rs.initiate(
    {
        _id: "shard1",
        version: 1,
        members: [
            { _id: 0, host: "ip-172-31-30-65.us-west-2.compute.internal:27017" },
            { _id: 1, host: "ip-172-31-17-88.us-west-2.compute.internal:27017" },
            { _id: 2, host: "ip-172-31-23-140.us-west-2.compute.internal:27017" }
        ]
    }
)
```

Also, when looking at your docker compose it looks like you start mongo2 with port 27018, which is fine, but then you map 27018 to 27017.  Shouldn't this be mapped to `27018:27018` instead?

Comment: Thank you Barrypicker, I tried to set all replica set parameters at once and I got the same error:

Comment: Did you correct your docker compose to expose the proper ports?

Comment: Yes I did, actually the problem is on the connection between the mongo services 
I tested it manually using this command ```mongo --host mongo_mongo02 --port 27018``` and i got this error  ```: Error connecting to mongo_mongo02:27018 (10.0.2.170:27018) :: caused by :: Connection refused  ```

Comment: I suspect errors running the mongo shell from the host system is caused by ingress problems, not mongo configuration problems.  Need to rule out mongo configuration problems first.  Can you get into the container and run the mongo shell (when inside the container) to verify mongo connectivity and configuration?  If you get errors connecting to mongo while inside the container then mongodb configuration changes are required.

Comment: Also, there could be issues with the persistent volumes.  MongoDB will choke if data directory is unavailable.